# How to specify language and region in maps api url

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, localization

I am trying to specify the language and region when referencing the maps api with the following urls in my script tag:

```
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=this-is-me&language=ja"
```

The above correctly display the map in Japanese.

Adding the region to the url reverts to displaying the default English map:

```
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=this-is-me&region=JP?language=ja"
```

I have tried various combinations of regions and languages and I cannot figure out if the two are supported together at all or which combinations are supported. The doc gives a list of supported languages but only says that 2 letters country codes can be used.

Comment: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=this-is-me&region=JP&language=ja`

Comment: @Dr.Molle Oops... it works very well with the right syntax. Thanks